# Does ML-Kit face detection for android supports GPU acceleration?

Tags: android, gpu, google-mlkit

I am performing real-time face detection in my application using ML-Kit API, and I am wondering if it supports gpu acceleration. The model works just fine. however when the resolution is kind of too high the inferance latency starts increasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the GPU acceleration is not supported yet but ML Kit is working on it will probably support multiple features including face detection in the future. Stay tuned!